# Pygame - Making a Sprite "walk" in the right direction

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I am continuing my work using pygame. I am currently working on the enemy class. Basically, it will walk from one side to another. I can get it to walk between the set boundaries, but I cannot get the image to display the proper direction the enemy is facing. If anyone can please help me out or give me some advice, I'd really appreciate it. Thank you.

I believe my issue is the update() function.

Here is my Enemy Class

```
class Enemies(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
     enemy_moving_frames_r = []
     enemy_moving_frames_l = []

     change_x = 0
     change_y = 0

     boundary_top = 0
     boundary_bottom = 0
     boundary_left = 0
     boundary_right = 0

     level = None
     player = None
def __init__(self):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    sprite_sheet = SpriteSheet("stuff/skeleton_7.png")

    image = sprite_sheet.get_image(7, 7, 28, 64)
    self.enemy_moving_frames_r.append(image)
    image = sprite_sheet.get_image(37, 7, 33, 64)
    self.enemy_moving_frames_r.append(image)
    image = sprite_sheet.get_image(70, 7, 33, 64)
    self.enemy_moving_frames_r.append(image)
    image = sprite_sheet.get_image(107, 7, 33, 64)
    self.enemy_moving_frames_r.append(image)
    image = sprite_sheet.get_image(142, 7, 33, 64)
    self.enemy_moving_frames_r.append(image)


    image = sprite_sheet.get_image(7, 7, 28, 64)
    image = pygame.transform.flip(image, True, False)
    self.enemy_moving_frames_l.append(image)
    image = sprite_sheet.get_image(37, 7, 33, 64)
    image = pygame.transform.flip(image, True, False)
    self.enemy_moving_frames_l.append(image)
    image = sprite_sheet.get_image(70, 7, 33, 64)
    image = pygame.transform.flip(image, True, False)
    self.enemy_moving_frames_l.append(image)
    image = sprite_sheet.get_image(107, 7, 33, 64)
    image = pygame.transform.flip(image, True, False)
    self.enemy_moving_frames_l.append(image)
    image = sprite_sheet.get_image(142, 7, 33, 64)
    image = pygame.transform.flip(image, True, False)
    self.enemy_moving_frames_l.append(image)


    self.image = self.enemy_moving_frames_r[0]
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()



def update(self):
    # Move left/right
    self.rect.x += self.change_x

    cur_pos = self.rect.x - self.level.world_shift

    print(cur_pos)

    if cur_pos < self.boundary_left:
        self.change_x *= -1
        frame = (self.rect.x // 30) % len(self.enemy_moving_frames_r)
        self.image = self.enemy_moving_frames_r[frame]
    elif cur_pos > self.boundary_right:
        self.change_x *= -1
        frame = (self.rect.x // 30) % len(self.enemy_moving_frames_l)
        self.image = self.enemy_moving_frames_l[frame]
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?  You should tell more about the behavior you are actually getting.  It looks like you are trying to change your animation when the sprite crosses a boundary, when you should be changing it based on the sprite's x velocity.

Comment: I am not getting any errors. The sprite "walks" but randomly switches from facing left/right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're only updating the frames when the enemy changes direction (i.e. when it hits one of the boundaries). However the frames should be updated each frame based on the current position and direction even when the sprite hasn't hit a boundary:

```
def update(self):
    # Move left/right
    self.rect.x += self.change_x

    cur_pos = self.rect.x - self.level.world_shift

    print(cur_pos)

    # test against boundaries:
    if cur_pos < self.boundary_left or cur_pos > self.boundary_right:
        self.change_x *= -1

    # set animation frame:
    if self.change_x > 0:
        frame = (self.rect.x // 30) % len(self.enemy_moving_frames_r)
        self.image = self.enemy_moving_frames_r[frame]
    elif self.change_x < 0:
        frame = (self.rect.x // 30) % len(self.enemy_moving_frames_l)
        self.image = self.enemy_moving_frames_l[frame]
```